# How do I get the single quotes to remain in the variable?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

This is a combination of classic ASP and Javascript, we are trying to insert a single quote around each itemno but it is not working.

It is ending up looking like this: 10234,12343,  instead of '10234','12343',

(The trailing comma I strip later)...

What can be done differently to keep the ItemNo's single quoted?

```
var Prefix_JS_Item = [<%For intA = 1 to intCount%><%="'" & trim(Mid(cartobj(intA).Item("ItemNo"),4)) & "',"%><%Next%>];
document.write(Prefix_JS_Item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been two attempts so far but try this:-

```
var Prefix_JS_Item = [<%For intA = 1 to intCount%><%="""'" & trim(Mid(cartobj(intA).Item("ItemNo"),4)) & "'"","%><%Next%>]; 
document.write(Prefix_JS_Item);
```

Javascript supports both " and ' to enclose a string literal.  So to include a ' in a literal you can use " to enclose the literal.  Now in VB to include a " in string literal you double them to "".

BTW, don't "quote" me (sorry) but in javascript I think you can get away with the trailing comma.

Comment: JavaScript is supposed to allow the trailing comma but IE doesn't support it (at least older versions. I haven't bothered to check on IE9)

Answer (score 2):

The script is doing what you want. The way you verify is what is wrong.

After ASP executes you will have `'10234','12343'` inside the JavaScript. To see it go to "view source code" (CTRL + U) in your browser.

Then you write it to the document. To JavaScript `'10234'` the quotes are delimiters for a string. Therefore it will only write what is inside them.

If you still want to have quotes even when writing it to the document then:

```
... <%="""'" &        trim(Mid(cartobj(intA).Item("ItemNo"),4)) & """," %>
document.write(Prefix_JS_Item);
```

Which in javascript will look like: `"'10234'","'12343'"`

**EDIT:** To scape quotes in ASP you use another quote.

Comment: Expected ')' Response.Write("\"'" & trim(Mid(cartobj(intA).Item("ItemNo"),4)) & "'\",")

Comment: @JoJo yeah i did not know that in asp you use quote to scape quotes.. in other languages "/" is used

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape the single quote

```
...<%="\'" & trim(Mid(cartobj(intA).Item("ItemNo"),4)) & "\',"%><%Next%>];
```